# Guide for complete daily prayer/blessings

Tags: tefilla, blessing, product-recommendation, jewish-books

I was raised secular/Christian (secular Jewish mom) and am reconnecting to my Judaism. I just moved to a place with no significant Jewish community or rabbis for a few hours.  (Luckily I lived in a big city and has an opportunity to learn a lot of Hebrew and about Jewish thought generally before I moved.) I'd really like some kind of concise guide, or even just a list, of the blessings/prayers and other activities involved in an observant Jewish life on a normal weekday so I can start incorporating them into my routine. As in, what do I do from the moment I wake up and say modeh ani til I go to bed (or at least through the morning)? Unfortunately the siddurim I have sort of presume your knowledge and I can't find a very complete guide online. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Hope you will find good answers and hope to see you around!

Comment: Despite the fact you say there's no rabbi for a few hours, I think this might be the sort of question that you would understand better hearing from a rabbi or by going to a synagogue and seeing what they do there. The question could be answered in many different ways. Almost every prayer book contains the binding of Isaac and the sacrifices as part of the morning service, for example, but very few people say it in practice. A rabbi might be better at determining how much you're willing to do in practice

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and commendations for your efforts. Offhand, I would recommend a "beginner's" / children's siddur. When I was a kid, we used Siddur Shilo. I don't think I would recommend it for you as it is completely in Hebrew, and my yeshiva emphasized Hebrew speaking. But, perhaps, Google that term, and browse. Let me see if I can ask my shul's rabbi or educational director what they recommend. There should be something at least "manageable".

Comment: Some clarification - Is your initial purpose to know what to pray / do? That doesn't really require a prayer book, per se, but a simple list. Or, do you want to understand the words in the prayers? If it's the latter, I wonder if one of Art Scroll's linear Siddurim would work for you? It has an English translation of each word below each Hebrew word.

Comment: To other viewers. Would Koren's *Ani Tefilla* or another Koren Siddur do the job?

Comment: I, too, commend you for your efforts and for reaching out here. I'll strongly second the suggestion above that you reach out to a rabbi for personal guidance; but as for generalities, I hope your question here gets good answers. But such an answer will vary widely: my own daily religious routine includes much more than the bare minimum one can possibly get away with; but then you may want yours to also, but to a greater/lesser extent than mine. So this is impossible to answer unless one lists either that minimum or a complete and comprehensive list. Can you clarify which of those two you want?

Comment: RShimon, I would be happy to quickly put together a guide for you. If you could tell me what siddur you currently have, I can put page numbers in for your convenience. Also, what is the nusach of the siddur? Ashkenaz I assume?

Comment: if you hebrew this is the best book for you: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01961.html

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for the great feedback and encouragement.  I think what I'm looking for is basically a list - I understand Hebrew well enough to understand the prayers themselves, especially with some help from translation.  My problem is that a siddur tends to include everything you need for an ordinary weekday but without much instruction on how to use it (what to read when or in what order). Right now I'm trying to use the Complete Artscroll Siddur but would be ok using about anything.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above focused on list of daily prayers but your original question was broader: "a concise guide of the blessings/prayers and other activities involved in an observant Jewish life on a normal weekday".

I would like to recommend two books I read cover to cover and really liked - which I believe perfectly fit your question. Both are compendium of laws of daily practice. Of course they also include Shabbat and holidays but as you grow in reconnecting to your Judaism these will become the next obvious questions.

- [Halacha 24/7/12](http://a.co/aYDijQs) - a very recent book which was originally written for yeshiva students as a set of "all the practical laws you need to know". It is remarkable in that it is both broad, highly accessible to everyone, incredibly practical and actually interesting to read. In a number of places the author show pragmatism by writing "Artscroll says X but basic halacha is Y". The goal of the author is to show halacha is not "[in the heaven or beyond the sea](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.12?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)" but instead very approachable
- [Shaarei Halachah](http://www.feldheim.com/shaarei-halachah.html) is a somewhat older book which aims to presents Jewish law in a simple and accessible way